# Hide ActionBar, keep tabs not working in Android Kitkat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to hide action bar, but keep tabs.
I used following codes, but this is not working for Android KitKat (Tested on Nexus 5).

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue out on Android KitKat?

Answer (score 0):

ActionBar tabs are part of the ActionBar, you can't display the tabs without the ActionBar.

Instead, you have to use [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html).

Comment: then, is there no way to hide that bar with settings icon on top of my tabs? Those two lines of codes worked though before KitKat.

Comment: "That bar with settings icon" is called [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) and its an essential element of Android UI/UX since Android 3 and 4. Removing it is not recommended for UX.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you didn't yet try:

```
actionbar.hide()
```

Comment: hmm..I already tried that. actionbar.hide() hides the whole action bar  including tabs. Before Android Kitkat, using those two lines of codes, only tabs without the empty bar with settings icon was appeared.